# How to capture error messages in R using evaluate

Tags: r, evaluate

I have a badly written function.

e.g.

```r
foo <- function (x) {
  y = log(x)
  if (y > 1) {
    print("hello")
  }
}
```

I call the function with a negative x argument.

```r
foo (-1)
```

I get an error and a warning because of the behaviour of log when called for a negative numeric.

```r
Error in if (y > 1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In log(x) : NaNs produced
```

I want to capture both the warning and the error message with the "evaluate" function.

This:

```r
output <- evaluate(foo(-1))
```

doesn't work. I just get the same warning + error message in the console. The "output" object is not created.

How do I capture error and warning message?

Comment: Check this `?tryCatch`

Comment: Thanks, I can try and go that way. But then "evaluate" is not meant for capturing errors?

Comment: The main purpose of package evaluate is providing the machinery for packages like knitr and rmarkdown that redirect R output.

Comment: Redirecting R output is what I am going for. Basically, if you run a function inside a markdown document and then render it, plots, errors, warnings etc. are displayed in a specific order/way in the report. I would like to access the different elements of the output individually so that I can choose how to display them in the report. E.g. inside a kable with one column for errors, one for warnings, one for plots...

Comment: Are you sure then that this should be addressed at the evaluate level and not at the rmarkdown level?

Comment: @Roland thanks :) I just came to a similar conclusion. Will try to weasle my way through rmarkdown.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at `try_capture_stack` from `evaluate`. This allows you to do:

```r
e <- suppressWarnings(try_capture_stack(foo(-1), env = parent.frame()))
if(is.error(e)) print(e$message) else print(e)
#> [1] "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

e <- suppressWarnings(try_capture_stack(foo(5), env = parent.frame()))
if(is.error(e)) print(e$message) else print(e)
#> [1] "hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the input:

```
foo <- function (x) {
  y = log(x)
  if (y > 1) {
    print("hello")
  }
}

foo (-1)
#> Warning in log(x): NaNs produced
#> Error in if (y > 1) {: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

output <- evaluate::evaluate("foo (-1)")
output
#> [[1]]
#> $src
#> [1] "foo (-1)"
#> 
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "source"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> <simpleWarning in log(x): NaNs produced>
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> <simpleError in if (y > 1) {    print("hello")}: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed>
```

Regards,